# Public maps not visible?

Tags: carto

I have two public maps, yet when I go to view them via the public links I get a page that says:

"Looks like this map no longer exists or is set as private"

All my datasets are public. Any thoughts on what's going on?

Public profile with maps visible: https://stephentracyis.cartodb.com/me

Map 1: https://stephentracyis.cartodb.com/viz/8bf8536e-8dbd-11e5-a522-0ecd1babdde5/public_map

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of the dataset? This problem might be caused by this bug:

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/6138

If the dataset (not the map!) is established as public and the name starts with an underscore it causes the error that you are describing.

To solve this you would need to change the dataset name. For example if the name of your dataset is "_dataset", change it into "dataset".